# NSIndexPath and IndexPath in Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, swift3

I have recently converted my code to Swift 3.0. My collection view and table view data source methods now contain `IndexPath` instead of `NSIndexPath` in their method signature. But still inside the method definition it is type casting IndexPath to NSIndexPath. i.e.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
    {
        let cell : NNAmenitiesOrFurnishingCollectionViewCell = self.amenitiesOrFurnishingCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "NNAmenitiesOrFurnishingCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! NNAmenitiesOrFurnishingCollectionViewCell
        cell.facilityImageName = self.facilityArray[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].imageName
        cell.facilityLabelString = self.facilityArray[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].labelText
        return cell
    }
```

Can anyone tell me why `indexPath` is type casted to `NSIndexPath`.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There is no reason to cast `IndexPath` to `NSIndexPath` here.
The Swift 3 overlay type `IndexPath` has properties

```
/// The section of this index path, when used with `UITableView`.
///
/// - precondition: The index path must have exactly two elements.
public var section: Int

/// The row of this index path, when used with `UITableView`.
///
/// - precondition: The index path must have exactly two elements.
public var row: Int
```

which you can access directly:

```
    cell.facilityImageName = self.facilityArray[indexPath.row].imageName
    cell.facilityLabelString = self.facilityArray[indexPath.row].labelText
```

Apparently the Xcode migrator did not a perfect job.

Comment: The reason to convert is if you are sending the IndexPath to a function that requires a NSIndexPath as an argument, or at least you need to in Swift 4.