# Swift 3 no subscript error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, parsing, uicollectionviewcell

During my conversion to swift 3 I encountered an error while trying to define the text of a label from my parse database. Here is the code where I define my cell:

```
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ExpandCell", for: indexPath) as! ExpandingCollectionViewCell

    let object = self.imageFilesArray[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]
    cell.nameLabel.text = String(describing: object["name"]).uppercased()

    return cell
```

On the line "cell.nameLabel.text...." I get an error stating 'Type Any has no subscript members.' I have searched all over and found people having similar issues but none that were able to help me here. Does anyone have any suggestions?

EDIT: Here is the code where I define imageFilesArray:

```
let query = PFQuery(className: "Events")

        query.order(byAscending: "dateString")
        query.findObjectsInBackground{
            (objects, error) -> Void in
            if error == nil {

                self.imageFilesArray = objects! as NSArray
```

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but the cast to NSIndexPath is not needed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39631905/nsindexpath-and-indexpath-in-swift-3-0.

Comment: What is self.imageFilesArray an array of?

Comment: They are PFObjects from Parse

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried casting your object variable to what it should be before trying to access it?

```
let object = self.imageFilesArray[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row] as [String:String]
```

Where [String:String] is whatever your object is trying to be.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
cell.nameLabel.text = String(describing: (object as AnyObject)["name"]).uppercased()
```

Comment: That didnt do it, it now states 'ambiguous use of subscript'

Comment: What is the declaration of imageFilesArray?
Can you set it to `var imageFilesArray: [PFObject] = []`

And change `self.imageFilesArray = objects! as NSArray` to `self.imageFilesArray = objects as! [PFObject]` then you should be able to use `object["name"]` without any casts.