# Swift 3 - Always get nil when cast values

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary, casting, swift3

I am currently having a bad time with type casting while fetching some data.

Here is the data I have in the debug console:

```
(7, ["name": Doe, "id": 2042, "website": http://somedomaine.com/, "logo": http://somedomaine.com/img/, "category_id": 33, "category": Institutional partners, "order": 7])
```

I am sure this is really obvious, but I can't figure out how to access to data like `name` or `id` and it is giving me headache. This is what I have done:

```
let section = ( index as NSIndexPath ).section + 1 as Int
let row = ( index as NSIndexPath ).row as Int

let sectionContent = posts![ section ] as? Array< Any >

let entry = ( sectionContent?[ row ] as AnyObject )
```

After that, the best I can get is `nil`!

Here is a little more details: the `posts` variable is initiated at the top of the class like so:

```
internal var posts: [ Int: AnyObject ]?
```

The data are parsed like this (the original data come from a json feed which is fine):

```
func parsePosts( posts: [ Dictionary< String, AnyObject > ] ) -> ( [ Int: AnyObject ], Int ) {

    var theCategories = [ Int : AnyObject ]()
    var theSponsors = [ Int : AnyObject ]()
    var theDict = [ Int : Array< Any > ]()

    for item in posts {

        let itemID = item[ "id" ] as! Int
        let sponsorMeta = item[ "sponsor_meta" ]
        let category = sponsorMeta?[ "category" ] as? String
        let title = item[ "title" ]
        let name = title?[ "rendered" ] as? String

        if !( category ?? "" ).isEmpty {

            let order = Int( ( sponsorMeta?[ "order" ] as? String )! )
            let categoryID = sponsorMeta?[ "category_id" ] as! Int
            let categoryOrder = sponsorMeta?[ "category_order" ] as! Int
            let website = sponsorMeta?[ "url" ] as? String
            let logo = sponsorMeta?[ "logo" ] as? [ String: Any ]
            let logoSizes = logo?[ "sizes" ] as? [ String: Any ]
            let imgUrl = logoSizes?[ "medium_large" ] as? String

            let sponsor = [ "id": itemID, "name": ( name )! as String, "logo": imgUrl! as String, "website": ( website )! as String, "category": category!, "order": order!, "category_id": categoryID ] as [ String : Any ]
            let category = [ "name": category!, "order": categoryOrder ] as [ String : Any ]

            theCategories[ categoryID ] = category as AnyObject
            theSponsors[ itemID ] = sponsor as AnyObject

        }

    }

    for ( k, value ) in theCategories {

        let categoryOrder = value[ "order" ] as! Int
        var catDict = [ Int : [ String: AnyObject ] ]()

        for ( _, element ) in theSponsors {

            let sponsorCategoryID = element[ "category_id" ] as! Int

            if sponsorCategoryID == k {

                let sponsorOrder = element[ "order" ] as! Int
                catDict[ sponsorOrder ] = element as? [ String : AnyObject ]

            }

        }

        let sortedCat = catDict.sorted( by: { $0.0 < $1.0 } )
        theDict[ categoryOrder ] = sortedCat

    }

    let sortedDict = theDict.sorted( by: { $0.0 < $1.0 } )
    var finalDict = [ Int: AnyObject ]()

    for ( t, v ) in sortedDict {
        finalDict[ t ] = v as AnyObject?
    }

    return ( finalDict, theCategories.count )

}
```

I am sure it is just a small thing but I have been playing for hours with casting types and I haven't found a solution.

Does anybody have a suggestion? It will be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but there should be no need to cast `index` to `NSIndexPath`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39631905/nsindexpath-and-indexpath-in-swift-3-0.

Comment: First of all the return type of `parsePosts` is a tuple, second of all you're using too much `Any(Object)` where the types are clearly more specific `String` or `Int`. Read the JSON and learn to understand and distinguish the types.

Comment: @vadian That was what I missed! Thanks! But for the other part of your comment, do you have any specific recommendations relative to the code above?

Answer (score 0):

I see that you have created a tuple and in order to access that data from that tuple I would suggest this approach

```
let posts = (7, dataDictioanry: ["name": "Doe", "id": 2042, "website": "http://somedomaine.com/", "logo": "http://somedomaine.com/img/", "category_id": 33, "category": "Institutional partners", "order": 7])

posts.dataDictioanry["name"]
```